# How to set up VS code to omit end tags in html files?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, specifications

I write in VS code 1.38.1 on Ubuntu/bionic 18.04.

I'm trying to follow [google's HTML styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Formatting_Rules) and skip [tags, specified as optional](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags) by [HTML Living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#toc-syntax)

I uninstalled the [HTML snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets) only to see it's last Update 5 - Disabling this extension as its functionality has been absorbed by VS Code main HTML extension.
Uninstalling it didn't change anything. I still have my tags closed

This is how HTML with omitted tags looks like

```
<ul>
  <li>Moe
  <li>Larry
  <li>Curly
</ul>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Income
      <th scope="col">Taxes
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$ 5.00
      <td>$ 4.50
</table>
```

Currently, as I write in HTML file VS Code closes all my tags automatically.
I want to be able to write tags in an HTML file without VS Code automatically closing them for me.
I want when I write

```
<li>
```

to have

```
<li>
```

but instead I get

```
<li></li>
```

and I have to manually delete

```
</li>
```

every time to follow [google's style guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Formatting_Rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code you go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> HTML -> Auto Closing Tags and uncheck the box.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017 Set *Options/Text Editor/HTML/Advanced -> Auto insert closing tag* to **false** may help